# How can I avoid a race condition between these two interlated threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

The little program I wrote consistently gets block due to what I think is a race condition. Can somebody kindly help me identifying my error?

There is one function, `process_two` which does some tasks and then relies on another function to update some underlying data structure before it may continue. **Note: this function is run by multiple threads simultaneously** This function is:

```cpp
void process_two(int n_tasks) {
    while (total_iter < 100) {
        // do some work
        iter_since_update += n_tasks;
        total_iter += n_tasks;
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lk(mutex);
        cv.wait(lk, [&] { return data_updated; });
        data_updated = false;
        lk.unlock();
    }
}
```

The function does some work and increments a count of the completed tasks. Then it acquires a shared lock (if possible), and waits for a condition variable. After having waited, the thread resets the condition and unlocks the mutex. The function updating the underlying data structure is:

```cpp
void process_one(int threshold) {
    while (total_iter < 100) {
        if (iter_since_update >= threshold) {
            std::lock_guard<std::shared_mutex> lk(mutex);
            // updating
            data_updated = true;
            iter_since_update = 0;
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever the other function has made some number of iterations, `process_one` acquires a lock and updates the data. It also resets the counter of iterations and notifies the other threads. Finally, the entire program is:

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int iter_since_update(0);
bool data_updated(true);
std::shared_mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable_any cv;
int total_iter(0);

void process_two(int n_tasks) {
    while (total_iter < 100) {
        // do some work
        iter_since_update += n_tasks;
        total_iter += n_tasks;
        std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lk(mutex);
        cv.wait(lk, [&] { return data_updated; });
        data_updated = false;
        lk.unlock();
    }
}

void process_one(int threshold) {
    while (total_iter < 100) {
        if (iter_since_update >= threshold) {
            std::lock_guard<std::shared_mutex> lk(mutex);
            // updating
            data_updated = true;
            iter_since_update = 0;
            cv.notify_all();
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int total_tasks(10);
    int n_threads(1);
    int n_tasks = total_tasks / n_threads;
    std::thread update_thread([&]() { process_one(total_tasks);});
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++)
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { process_two(n_tasks); }));
    while (total_iter < 100) {
        ;
    }
    update_thread.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) threads[i].join();
}
```

I set a total number of tasks  and let each thread running  `process_two` do a fraction of these tasks.  Whenever I set `n_threads = 1`, the program completes almost always. Whenever I set `n_threads = 2`, the program always failed.

I am new to multithreading in c++ and would greatly appreciate any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong.  I suspect that the condition in `process_one` (waiting until a number of iterations have been done) is wrong.  Whenever I saw condition variables being used in examples in Anthony Williams' wonderful book (see section 4.1.1. in the 2012 edition) one function was operating until an **external condition** is negated but here I have both processes depending on each other.  Can somebody kindly point out what I can improve?

Comment: `iter_since_update += n_tasks` is a data race already. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Those calculations you are doing before you get the mutex are not atomic.  `iter_since_update += n_tasks; total_iter += n_tasks;`  -- All sorts of things can happen in-between those calculations if two or more threads are hitting that function.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if, in `process_one`, the optimizer hoists `iter_since_update >= threshold` check out of the `while` loop and performs it only once. After all, In a race-free program, there's no way for `iter_since_update` to change after that check. In fact, it might optimize away the whole loop, since `total_iter` can't change either.